# Finding $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f : [0,\infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and periodic. Let $g(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, for all $x\geq 0.$ Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. Find $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}.$$

I claimed, $f$ is a constant, as it is periodic and has limit at infinity, so $g(x)=Lx$. Hence 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{x}=L$$

Is it a valid argument?

Comment: Why must $f$ be constant? The map $x\mapsto\sin(x)$ is also continuous and periodic.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas it doesn't have a limit at infinity.

Comment: How can a periodic function has a limit at $\infty$?

Comment: Why these downvotes ? This is a perfectly valid and interesting post.

Comment: I guess some of the people don't have enough info about Periodic functions!

Comment: @MyGlasses if it's a constant!

Comment: @Parisina: anyway, continuity and periodicity aren't required at all in this problem. $\lim f=L$ is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is continuity necessary for integrability?

Comment: @MyGlasses: no, it's not.

Comment: Your argument is correct. But then it makes the problem trivial if $f$ is periodic and therefore constant. One just needs integrability of $f$ on any bounded interval and the existence of limit of $f$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I read the problem wrong, in the original question the function $f$ was only periodic, not continuous. I'd already had different solution and I was wondering why, then I posted my solution, to double check. Actually the problem is challenging when $f$ is only periodic. Anyway, I have my solutions now.

Answer (score 4):

If  $f$ is continuous then $g(x)$ is differentiable thus

$$\lim_{x \to + \infty} \frac{g(x)}{x}=L$$   from L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: That is the fastest way to go.  And we don't even need to know whether or not $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)$ exists!

Comment: Can we use this argument, if $f$ is continuous $f$ is Riemann integrable, so $g$ is a  Lipschitz continuous function. Then $$|g(x)-g(y)|\le K|x-y|$$

Comment: I'm afraid i do not understand your question